# SQL Impact of updating zero rows

Tags: sql, performance, sql-update

Are there any impacts that updating zero rows has which may merit checking that there are rows that match your criteria before making the update?

Table A has a user which has a status which may be 1, 2, or 3. Table B has a decimal value. If the decimal value in table B is greater than 35 and the status of the user in table A is 1, it is updated to 2.

Currently I'm just joining the two in an update without checking to see if there is a record to update. As such, if table B has a value of 20 there are no row to update or if the user in table A is already set to 2, there is also no row to update. I know this works, but I'm wondering what kind of impacts this has if any vs performing a select statement beforehand and only updating if there is a result.

Comment: Edit your question and (1) show the query you are using and (2) tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You should continue doing what you are doing, for the following two reasons:

- **A check that says "you need to update" may be a false positive** - in a concurrent environment some other process may push an update ahead of your update but after your check, so it is better to perform an update in one go
- **An extra roundtrip would kill performance** - you would nearly double the number of roundtrips in situations when most checks result in an update. Roundtrips to RDBMS tend to degrade performance much more than operations internal to your RDBMS.

**Note:** The above assumes that both the read and the update query have been properly optimized.

Comment: I didn't fully understand the question.  This is definitely the right answer.